# Carrousel only show the images for the first post and not on the others

Tags: python, html, django

I'm developing a app in django in which I need to show multiple post and each post has multiple images that I want to put in a carrousel, my problem is that only the first post show its images, the next ones can't show them inside the carrousel, but can be shown in other parts of the template.
Here's the model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Rifa."""

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=50)
    
    fecha_inicio = models.DateTimeField('fecha inicio', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    fecha_termino = models.DateTimeField('fecha termino', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product:product_detail', args=[str(self.id)])   
    def __str__(self):
       return self.nombre

class PhotoProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.nombre
```

Here's the views.py

```
class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['photo_list'] = PhotoProduct.objects.all()
        return context
```

Here´s the template

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            {% for photo in photo_list %}
            {% if photo.product.pk == product.pk %}
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
              class="{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}"></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for photo in photo_list %}
            {% if photo.product.pk == product.pk %}
            <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}">
              <img src="{{photo.photo.url}}" class="img-fluid d-block w-100" style="height: 300px;" alt="...">
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I inspect the elements in the browser, the first product show 1, 2, 3... in the forloop counter, but the second product start at 4, I need to now how do I restart the counter in forloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use boostarp owl carousel this way. this can get you some idea. you can check this doc as well https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-carousel ">  
      
<div class="owl-carousel carousel-main">

  {% for photo in photo_list %}

         <img src="{{photo.photo.ur}}"> 

          
        {% endfor %}

  </div>
```

jquery for the carousel. you can reference this doc https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.carousel-main').owlCarousel({
 autoPlay: false,
 center: true,
 items: 3,
 loop: true,
 stopOnHover : true,
 autoplayTimeout: 1500,
 margin: 10,
 navigation: true,
 dots: false,
 navigationText: ['<span class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></span>','<span class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></span>'],
```

});